# File, View, etc menus not appearing

Tags: unity

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10. None of my applications are showing their menus in the menu bar at the top of the screen, eg. File, Tools, etc. All I see is "Activities" and then a drop down menu titled with the name of the applicatin (which contains only a single option, "Quit").

Comment: Surely you're using GNOME instead of Unity.

Comment: @pomsky Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you run Unity? Ubuntu runs gnome instead of Unity [since 17.10](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/ubuntu-17-10-return-of-the-gnome/). One of the consequence is that the top menu is no longer.

I think you can still install Unity (package `ubuntu-unity-desktop`) in 18.10.

BTW gnome is moving away from menus towards "hamburger" buttons, or so it seems [src](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/gnome-app-menu-migration).

If an app doesn't implement the new hamburger button, it will still show the top menu in the window (like in MS Windows), e.g. the gnome-terminal:

[image: gnome-terminal]

Comment: Is there an equivalent to the menu bar in gnome? Some (most?) applications depend on the menu bar for key functionality.

Comment: Updated the response with a note on that.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was specific to VSCode - due to a bug in that specific app, the menubar wasn't appearing (same color font as background).